# Not trigger any events (e.g. click) when a specific input field loses focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Let's say I have an input text field and a few anchor links.

1. The user cursor is focused in the input text field.
2. When the user clicks on one of the links outside this field, the input field loses focus and a click event is triggered (bad - **I just want the first click outside to be an action to lose the focus of that input field**).

Only subsequent clicks would be triggered once this input field is no longer in focus.

Comment: lemme get this straight: an input element is focused, and when you click on something outside of it, it fires a click event, but when you click that thing again, it doesn't fire? so, only the first click event after the input loses focus is fired?

Comment: let me clarify. an input element is focused, when i click on something outside of it, it fires a click event (bad - i want it to ignore this click event). when i click again on that thing, (good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use onblur event listener on the text field that will put a flag to indicate that user just left this "magic" input. Then, check this flag in "onclick" events in anchors and if the flag is true, call "prevent default" (and/or return the focus to the input).
Optionally clear the flag after a small timeout.

Comment: i was thinking that could be done...but surely there can be a cleaner approach? :) thanks!

Comment: Well, as for me it looks like the best you can do, you can also add the global listener to the document, and "preventDefault" there - will be a little bit cleaner and you will not need to track every individual anchor.

Comment: How do I go about adding a global listener? Thanks!

Comment: $(document).click(function(e) {
   // This is "global" one
});

Of course it will fire for every click event in the whole page. So you will have to filter only what you need. Like checking the original element in the event object